# How to prove you live somewhere when you live at some friend house for the National Insurance Number in UK?

Tags: working, paperwork, insurance

Got a problem : I will apply for the National Insurance Number in UK, I need to prove I live somewhere they ask me for an invoice with my name ... : / Yet I live at my friend's house ... How can I prove it then ? Should I sleep in an hostel for a day ?  I asked my friend about the lodget agreement but she answered me *a lodger agreement would mean my mum's household income would be higher so it would be bad for her.*

Here is the official link about applying for a National Insurance Number :

https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number

So far I have tried to open an account up and put our address on there, so that I have something official as Bank statements seems to be a good thing to prove address. Yet I told them I had no revenue but no mortage and that I lived with these friends since a bit less than a month and I got this message :

[image] :

> UNFORTUNATELY, WE CAN'T OFFER YOU A CURRENT ACCOUNT AT THIS TIME Hi
>   Mr XXX,
>
> We're very sorry, but we won't be able to offer you a Current Account
>   at this time, as the submitted application didn't meet our criteria..
>
> We came to this decision after looking over your personal details, as
>   well as information from trusted third parties including the Credit
>   Reference Agency (CRA).
>
> It may be worth checking that your Photo ID image is clear as this can
>   also play a part in our decision.
>
> In line with data protection regulation, you can review how we use and
>   store the information you give us here.
>
> If you have any questions, please call us on 0345 08 08 500 or visit
>   us in store

I ask this question there following [an advice from David K on Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/121980/how-to-prove-you-live-somewhere-when-you-live-at-some-friend-house-for-the-natio)

Comment: What is your nationality? If you are paying to live at your friend’s house, you should ask for a tenancy agreement. The person receiving the payment may need to a) declare it as taxable income or b) advise relevant organisation(s) if they are receiving any social security benefits or a council tax reduction. https://www.gov.uk/report-benefits-change-circumstances.

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for your help. I'm French and I'm not paying at my friend's house.  asked my friend about the lodget agreement but she answered me _a lodger agreement would mean my mum's household income would be higher so it would be bad for her._

Comment: Passenger Which bank did you apply to? The ‘visit us in store’ response doesn’t sound like a phrase a bank would use.

Comment: @Traveller [metro bank](https://apply.metrobankonline.co.uk/apply/)

Comment: You may need to check which banks offer a ‘basic’ account https://moneyfacts.co.uk/guides/banking/can-you-open-an-account-without-proof-of-address/ and what documentation each requires to open an account. Regarding your original question about getting a NINO, you could try going to your local Job Centre to ask their advice.

Comment: Hello Passenger, I followed you here from the Workplace. AFAICS there is no legal definition for a _lodger_, but you don't actually have to pay rent, or you can pay something like £1. The difference between lodger and guest is quite blurry. I hate to send you over to another site, but the folks over at Law.SE may have some insight into this

Comment: Asked at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/33337/10503) to clarify